# How do I add Annotations from function to my map?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I need to add annotations to my map from Cloud Firestore...
In Cloud Firestore my annotations are stored this way:
"document id" with fields "latitude" and "longitude"...
So I get them with this function:

```
func getAnnotations() {

    FirestoreReferenceManager.referenceForAnnotations().addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, err) in
        
        guard (querySnapshot?.documents) != nil
            else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
        
        for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

            let lat = document.get("latitude") as! String
            let lon = document.get("longitude") as! String
                        
            let latitude =  Double(lat)
            let longitude = Double(lon)
            let truecoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude ?? 0, longitude: longitude ?? 0)
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.coordinate = truecoordinate
        }
    }
}
```

And the map itself is declared in another file:

```
struct MapView: View {
@State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 55.791, longitude: 37.711617),
    span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02)
    )
var body: some View {
    Map(coordinateRegion: $region)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
}
}
```

So my question is: How do I make an array of annotations which I got from DataBase (Cloud Firestore) and add them to my map which I declared in another file in SwiftUI?

UPD: got a full answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67024708/15584529)

Comment: See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66701058/swiftui-mapkit-binding-mapkit-and-show-view-on-annotation-callout-buttons/66755580#66755580)

Comment: I have a Struct for annotations, but when I try to add annotations there I get an error: "Cannot convert value of type 'MKPointAnnotation' to expected argument type 'Annotation'", so I still can't make an array of annotations